# Is there a way to track the data transferred for a user when they access your site?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Has anyone come across a solution to tracking how much data users are using when accessing your site? Something similar to the "transferred over network" metric shown when using the Developer Tools. Does anyone know whether there is any variable that can be accessed to retrieve this information?

Comment: Do you mean when a user logs in?

Answer (score 0):

#### window.performance.memory

Closest information about consuming resources can be from performance.memory API availiable in Chrome.

I recalculate this value from bytes of browsers used memory into rounded Megabytes,

```
function bytesToMB(bytes) {
   if (bytes == 0) return '0';
   return parseInt(Math.round(bytes / 1024 / 1024));    
}

if(window.performance && window.performance.memory){
  var currentMemoryUsage = window.performance.memory.totalJSHeapSize;
}

console.log(currentMemoryUsage);
console.log(bytesToMB(currentMemoryUsage));
```

#### Google Analytics settings

Setup **Custom Metric**, eg. `cm1` **HIT** scope, Integer

And you can send it with every PageView event.

Then you may see aggregated number shows data loaded by users browsing.

#### GTM installation

Create custom JavaScript Variable.

```
function () {
  if(window.performance && window.performance.memory){
    var c = window.performance.memory.totalJSHeapSize
    return c == 0 ? 0 : parseInt(Math.round(c/1048576));
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

And use it in your Google Analytics Custom Metric Config when page loads.

#### Problems of this solution

- You can't distinguis between cached data in a browser and data that wen't over the internet data
- It is hard to detect additional dynamic data, such as video stream etc.
- It works only in Chrome (and maybe a few other browsers, but not FF and IE)

#### So it is not possible directly in a way you are asking, but we can get close.